# Next Closest Pair Problem

Tags: math, graph, graph-theory

I'm sure most are familiar with the [closest pair problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem), but is there another alogrithm or a way to modify the current CP algorithm to get the *next* closest pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy one, in O(n log(n)) :

- find the closets pair (p1,p2) in O(n log(n))
- compute all pairs with p1 or p2 (but not (p1,p2)) keep the closest one, let's call it `E` in O(n)
- remove p1 and p2 in (1)
- find the closets pair, compare it to `E` and keep the closest one, again in O(n log(n))

You now have the second closest one.

Comment: Do you know if there is an efficient way to generalize this process so you can obtain the kth closest pair? Preferably in a way that is not O(n!)?

Comment: @Tyler : just do k times the processus, so `O(k.n.log(n))`

Answer (score 0):

If constant number of minimal distances (*next* pairs) are needed, it is possible to modify steps 3-5, from Wikipedia article, redefining d_Lmin, d_Rmin, d_LRmin as constant length lists of minimum distances. That uses c*log(n) memory.

If *next* is  used  less than O(n) times, than reformulation of CR problem to return smaller distance larger than given *d* is same as *next* method. It can be implemeted with same approach as CR. I don't see theoretical guaranty that step 4 can be accomplished in linear time, but there is advantage not to check points in to small boxes.

If *next* is used more than O(n) times, than it is the best to calculate all distances and sort them (if memory is not a problem).